# How to change size of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have three radio buttons that I want to use to change the size of a JTextArea when I click the buttons.

```
if(rd_7inch.isSelected())
{
    jScrollPane2.setSize(200,200);
    txt_sysnp.setSize(5,20);
}if(rd_9inch.isSelected())
{
    jScrollPane2.setSize(200,200);
    txt_sysnp.setSize(5,25);
}if(rd_10inch.isSelected())
{
    jScrollPane2.setSize(200,200);
    txt_sysnp.setSize(5,30);
}
```

Comment: It is likely that you components are under the control of a layout manager.  The only means by which you can suggest changes to the size would be to use `setColumns` and `setRows` and use a layout manager that respects the preferred size of its components

Comment: Which layout you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you components are under the control of a layout manager.

The only means by which you can suggest changes to the size would be to use `setColumns` and `setRows` and use a layout manager that respects the preferred size of its components

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TextAreaSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextAreaSize();
    }

    public TextAreaSize() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JRadioButton btnSmall = new JRadioButton(new SizeAction("Small", 2, 10));
            JRadioButton btnMed = new JRadioButton(new SizeAction("Medium", 4, 15));
            JRadioButton btnLarge = new JRadioButton(new SizeAction("Large", 12, 24));
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(btnSmall);
            bg.add(btnMed);
            bg.add(btnLarge);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            add(btnSmall, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(btnMed, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(btnLarge, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            ta = new JTextArea();
            add(new JScrollPane(ta), gbc);

            btnSmall.doClick();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public class SizeAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int rows;
            private int columns;

            public SizeAction(String name, int rows, int columns) {
                putValue(NAME, name);
                this.rows = rows;
                this.columns = columns;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ta.setRows(rows);
                ta.setColumns(columns);
                revalidate();
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The important point is that whenever you update the UI you have to call revalidate() on that panel or container so that your changes get apply.

You can also do this by setSize() method.

```
public void showDialog(){
         btnUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dimSPane.setSize(new Dimension(400,50));
                pane.revalidate();
            }
        });
       btnUp.setSize(new Dimension(100,24));
         btnDn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dimSPane.setSize(new Dimension(200,25));
                pane.revalidate();
            }
        });
       btnDn.setSize(new Dimension(100,24));
        dimSPane.setSize(new Dimension(200,25));
        Dimension dimtfield = new Dimension();
        dimtfield.setSize(new Dimension(200,25));
        spane.setMinimumSize(dimSPane);
        spane.setMaximumSize(dimSPane);
        spane.setPreferredSize(dimSPane);
        tfield.setMinimumSize(dimtfield);
        tfield.setMaximumSize(dimtfield);
        tfield.setPreferredSize(dimtfield);
        pane.add(spane);
        pane.add(tfield);
        pane.add(btnUp);
        pane.add(btnDn);
        JDialog dlg =new JDialog();dlg.add(pane);
        dlg.pack();
                dlg.show();
    }
```

[image]
[image]